# Parallel call with flatMap in Rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2

```
public interface ASarTaLineApi {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("GetWarDee.php")
Observable<GetWardeeResponse> getWardee(@Field("access_token") String access_token);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("GetMealShop.php")
Observable<GetMealShopResponse> getMealShop(@Field("access_token") String access_token);}
```

How to call parallel with flatMap in RxJava.I want two Object at the same time.Please answer me details and I don't understand kotlin.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zipWith` for a parallel operation like this:

```
String token = "hello";
api.getMealShop(token)
        .zipWith(api.getWardee(token), new BiFunction<GetMealShopResponse, GetWardeeResponse, Pair<GetMealShopResponse, GetWardeeResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public Pair<GetMealShopResponse, GetWardeeResponse> apply(GetMealShopResponse getMealShopResponse, GetWardeeResponse getWardeeResponse) throws Exception {
                return new Pair<>(getMealShopResponse, getWardeeResponse);
            }
        });
```

Or lambda'd:

```
api.getMealShop(token)
        .zipWith(api.getWardee(token), Pair::new);
```

You get back an `Observable<Pair<GetMealShopResponse, GetWardeeResponse>>`. If that's what not you want, just put something else in the zipper parameter.